# How to solve this approximate distribution problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ...,X_n$ are random samples from Bernoulli Distribution with $p \lt \frac{1}{2}$ and $\bar X_n$ be its sample mean. Try to find the approximate distribution of $T_n = \sqrt{\bar X_n} + \sqrt{1 - \bar X_n}$ for large n.

For this problem, I intuitively guess that I need to approximate it to normal distribution, but I don't know how I should deal with it. Any help or hint is welcome!

Comment: If you can approximate $\bar{X}_n$ with a normal distribution, you can then use delta method to approximate the distribution of $T_n$ with a normal distribution. The fact that $p<1/2$ is key.

Comment: Could you please write a little bit for me, I am still confused what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: If the samples are iid then $T_n$ converges to a constant with prob 1. If no dependency info is given then the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @Michael I'm guessing the aim is to find the asymptotic distribution of an appropriate normalization of the statistic such that it is not asymptotically degenerate. That is typically what is meant when the asymptotic distribution of a statistic is asked for.

Comment: @Cooper Try starting off with the central limit theorem to find the asymptotic distribution of $\bar X_n$ and then see how the delta method can be applied